# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromSeedBuffer' of undefined

Tags: javascript, bitcoinjs, mnemonic-seed, node.js

I am getting Getting error at this line
**var root = bitcoin.HDNode.fromSeedBuffer(seed);**

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'fromSeedBuffer' of undefined

Here is the code snippet to generate bitcoin address:

```
'use strict'

var bip39 = require('bip39');
var bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib');

var mnemonic = bip39.generateMnemonic();
if (bip39.validateMnemonic(mnemonic)) {
    console.log('\nThe mnemonic is \n' + mnemonic);
    var seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic);
    var root = bitcoin.HDNode.fromSeedBuffer(seed);
    var dp = root.derivePath("m/140'/0'/0'/0/5");

    console.log('\nThe Address is \n' + dp.getAddress());    
} else {

}
```

Where bitcoinjs-lib v4.0.0 and 
      bip39 v2.5.0 and node v8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `bip32` module. Also there are a few other things you'll need to fix as well. See [Use BIP39 to generate BIP32 addresses](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/blob/master/test/integration/bip32.js#L86). Note, this will generate a `P2PKH` address, see `getAddress()` function.

**index.js:**

```
'use strict'

var bip39 = require('bip39');
var bip32 = require('bip32');
var bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib');

function getAddress (node, network) {
  return bitcoin.payments.p2pkh({ pubkey: node.publicKey, network }).address
}

var mnemonic = bip39.generateMnemonic();
if (bip39.validateMnemonic(mnemonic)) {
    console.log('\nThe mnemonic is \n' + mnemonic);
    var seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic);
    var root = bip32.fromSeed(seed);
    var dp = root.derivePath("m/140'/0'/0'/0/5");

    console.log('\nThe Address is \n' + getAddress(dp));    
} else {

}
```

**Output:**

```
$ node index.js

The mnemonic is
assume victory kiwi swarm furnace firm thumb exact dizzy crucial neglect certain

The Address is
1FYtPnUZZ2ZJL2fZ6XehGtkHfujUHkqK3T
```

Comment: Hi @JBaczuk help to get privatekey for this address 1FYtPnUZZ2ZJL2fZ6XehGtkHfujUHkqK3T........ from the above process I got address but I do't get any way to get privatekey

Comment: Try `dp.privateKey`